# Customize grub menu label in Debian live build

Tags: debian, live-usb

I am trying to roll my own distro using [Debian live](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLive), following [this documentation](https://debian-live.alioth.debian.org/live-manual/stable/manual/html/live-manual.en.html). Everything is fine in that the compiled iso runs/installs perfectly, and has the name I have specified in the config file ("MY_LINUX"). However, one peculiar problem is that after installation, the grub menu does not show "MY_LINUX", but "*Debian GNU/Linux". I have searched all the documentation, including the lb-config and lb-build manpages, but have not been able to figure out what option I need to put in where, so that the grub menu shows the name of my distro ("MY_LINUX"), and not the default. Do I have to put in a grub.cfg file before building the image? My config file is given below:

```
     #!/bin/sh

set -e

lb config noauto \
    -b iso-hybrid \
    --apt-options "--force-yes --yes" \
    --cache true \
    --apt-recommends true \
    --architecture amd64 \
    --mirror-bootstrap "http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/" \
    --mirror-chroot "http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/" \
    --archive-areas "main contrib non-free" \
    --parent-archive-areas "main contrib non-free" \
    --debian-installer live \
    --mode debian \
    --debian-installer-gui true \
    --win32-loader false  \
    --grub-splash "/boot/grub/spash.png" \
    --security true \
    --backports true \
    --updates true \
    --image-name "MY_LINUX" \
    --verbose \

    "${@}"
```

Comment: I'm not sure in `/etc/default/grub` `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian``

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need a grub.cfg in your installation disks boot directory. The GRUB 2 (assuming you are using GRUB 2) configuration file, grub.cfg, is generated during installation, or by invoking the `/usr/sbin/grub2-mkconfig` utility, and is automatically updated by grubby each time a new kernel is installed. So you need to generate the grub.cfg at install time with proper label and other details (kernel/initrd locations etc.). Also you need to install GRUB in disk prior to generating grub.cfg.
When generating the grub.cfg using `grub2-mkconfig`, the file is generated according to the template files located in `/etc/grub.d/`, and custom settings in the /etc/default/grub file. Edits of grub.cfg will be lost any time `grub2-mkconfig` is used to regenerate the file, so care must be taken to reflect any manual changes in `/etc/default/grub` as well.
Hope that helps you get the flow. Check [Red Hat - System administration guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader.html) for more details on grub.cfg file configuration.

Comment: Thanks, Joy. Does that mean I have to include grub.cfg in the  /includes.chroot/boot/grub/ directory before running "lb build"?

Comment: Yep, exactly. You need to configure the grub file before live build.